# Filtering records by user email in App Engine Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app hosted on app engine. It has some fields along with the UserProperty() as shown below:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created_by = db.UserProperty(required=True)
    ...#some other fields
```

I am trying to filter records by created_by field, so that app will display records created by logged in user. I tried:

```
p = Post.all()
p.filter('created_by =', users.get_current_user())
```

Which is not working. Please help.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem you should describe how it is not working, do you get an error, no results, results but not the one you expect ?  Having said all of that have you investigated what is stored in UserProperty using the datastore viewer.

Comment: I didn't get any error, but no result. And in datastore 'created_by' column has user's email id. BTW, I used 'users.get_current_user()' while filling the 'created_by' field. There were no result(p.count() is 0) even after issuing - p.filter('created_by =' '<stored_email_id>')

Comment: Consider switching to [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a separated model for your logged in users you should store in the post also the `user_id` and not the `email`, since the former is more unique.

Just add one more field in the `Post`

```
class Post(db.Model):
  title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  created_by = db.UserProperty(required=True)
  user_id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  ...
```

And on `Post` creation do something like this:

```
post_db = Post(title='Hello world', 
               created_by=users.get_current_user(), 
               user_id=users.get_current_user().user_id())
```

Now if you want to show all the posts that was made by the logged in user you should:

```
p = Post.all()
p.filter('user_id =', users.get_current_user().user_id())
```

Comment: I just found out, created_by holds the user instance because I used 'created_by = users.get_current_user()' while creating post. What confused me is Datastore viewer is showing user's email id in created_by field. I will use your method by storing extra field.
But I didn't get why user_id is more unique than email id?

Comment: @rajpy actually in your case is the same since you'are not changing it in any way in your app. But in general for within the app the email of the actual user might change so you should never rely on the email for the uniqueness. It's just bad practice..